# JS onclick event doesn't work in firefox but work in chrome based on codeigniter & bootstrap

Tags: javascript

I have this code to fill the field based on data in table triggered by on click `updateinputSediaModal` that echo 1 data-id to trigger ajax function for populate the `updateinputSediaModal` field forms, it populate function work in chrome browser but not in firefox.

In my View Page

```
<table id="inputsedia_tb" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">#</th>
                                <th scope="col">Kode Persediaan</th>
                                <th scope="col">Jurusan</th>
                                <th scope="col">Uraian</th>
                                <th scope="col">Satuan</th>
                                <th scope="col">User Penginput</th>
                                <th scope="col">Tanggal Input</th>
                                <th scope="col">Aksi</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php $i = 1; ?>
                            <?php foreach ($sediaMaster as $sm) : ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row"><?= $i; ?></th>
                                    <td><?= $sm['id_sedia']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?= $sm['nama_jur']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?= $sm['nama_sedia']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?= $sm['sedia_satuan']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?= $sm['user_input']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?= $sm['tgl_input']; ?></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updateinputSediaModal" class="badge badge-success updateinputSediaModal" data-id="<?= $sm['id_sedia']; ?>">Ubah</a>
                                        <a href="<?= base_url('persediaan/delmasterSedia/') . $sm['id_sedia']; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Menghapus master data barang ini akan menghapus semua data yang berkaitan dengan barang ini (stok masuk, stok keluar dan sisa stok), anda ingin melanjutkan ?')" class="badge badge-danger">Hapus</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php $i++ ?>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

<!-- Modal Update Menu -->
<div class="modal fade" id="updateinputSediaModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="updateinputSediaLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="updateinputSediaLabel">Update Data Persediaan</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form action="<?= base_url('persediaan/updatemasterSedia') ?>" method="post">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id_sediaUpd" id="id_sediaUpd">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="namasediaUpd" name="namasediaUpd" placeholder="Nama Barang Praktik">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="satuanUpd" name="satuanUpd" placeholder="Satuan">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nikUpd" name="nikUpd" value="<?= $user['nik']; ?>" readonly>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Tutup</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ubah</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my footer page

```
<script>
    //script update input persediaan (persediaan/input persediaan)
    $('.updateinputSediaModal').on('click', function() {
        const id = $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?= base_url('persediaan/getSediaid'); ?>",
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {
                $("#id_sediaUpd").val(data[0].id_sedia);
                $("#namasediaUpd").val(data[0].nama_sedia);
                $("#satuanUpd").val(data[0].sedia_satuan);
                $("#nikUpd").val(data[0].user_input);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

can I get explain how this happening ?

Comment: Is there an actual line break in the class attribute or is it just how you added the code?

Comment: Do you have exceptions in your browser console?

Comment: The logic is on an `<a>` tag and you haven't shown where the click event is being prevented from transfering pages.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] and add the relevant tags (what is `$`?).

Comment: @epascarello there is actual line break in the class attribute, if I insert the whole code its too much to read I think, because the main problem is happening only in this code, but if you need the whole code I'll update it

Comment: @RomanEpifanov I have no exceptions in my firefox console, it works wells

Comment: @Taplar I tried to update the code, pls feel free to check my code

Comment: @Andreas okay sir, Im updating the code, feel free to check my code

Comment: Where in your code do you initialise the jquery script? Perhaps you are getting $ is not defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see where you are defining jQuery, so are you getting $ is not defined error?

Another thing I notice is you have `$('.updateinputSediaModal')` but I do not see any class called **updateinputSediaModal** however I do see this element;

`<div class="modal fade" id="updateinputSediaModal" ...`

So perhaps change `$('.updateinputSediaModal')` to be `$('#updateinputSediaModal')`?

As it is an ID not a CLASS.

Comment: yeah, I just watch the tutorial how to make modal fade in and out and the trigger is `data-target="#updateinputSediaModal"` from table, but I think not all browser can support that

Comment: @GstiAld they can. That tag isn't a browser tag, it's a script tag that something like bootstrap uses for all its functions etc. Be careful when playing with that, particularly if your site uses bootstrap.